# use cypress to change angular proxy.conf.json headers

Tags: angular, proxy, cypress

Currently using Cypress 12.8 and Angular 15.2.  I have a proxy.conf.json file set up in an Angular project that sends requests for localhost:4200/api to server.com/path/to/api that sends a variable to the server in the header.  Something like:

```
headers: {
  foo: baz
}
```

The foo header is read by the api and depending on its value, different sets of data are returned.  Based on what the api returns, Angular displays different elements on the page.  So far so good.

But I want to run some Cypress tests and change `baz` to `bar` and `foobar` and `rebar` without having to stop the test and re-serve the app.  The docs make it sound like this should be possible, but what I have isn't working.

```
cy.intercept({pathname: '/testme', query: '*'}, (req) => {
      req.headers['foo'] = 'rebar'
}).visit('http://localhost:4200/testme');
```

The angular page displays with baz, which is what is in proxy.conf.json.

I think I just have dueling proxies going on.  Cypress intercepts the .visit('http://localhost:4200/test') command and sets foo=rebar, then passes control on to Angular, which uses the setting in *its* proxy and set foo=baz when it requests server.com/path/to/api.

So far the best solution I've come up with is to have multiple proxy.conf.json files, multiple configurations in my angular.json and then do `concurrently "ng serve --configuration=rebar" "cypress open"` run the tests for rebar, then repeat for bar and baz.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options come to mind.

From the Angular side, add **Serve configurations**. Add a non-proxy configuration to `angular.json`

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:qa"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

In `package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:qa": "ng serve --configuration=qa",
```

---

From the Cypress side, use **mocks in the intercept** to return the data you need for the test.

```js
cy.intercept({pathname: '/testme', query: '*'}, (req) => {
  req.reply({something})
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was pretty much what I came up with too.  I was hoping for a way to avoid adding a bunch of different settings and fixtures for all of the different roles that I have to test.  3 wouldn't be too bad, but the client wants almost a dozen roles with slightly different settings and there's just no talking them out of it.  Going to have to increase their budget for all of that testing I guess.